# How to change heroku's node.js buildpack to run a script other than build

Tags: angular, heroku, deployment, mean-stack, staging

I have an application, foobar, whose file structure is like this:

- /Client
- /api
- package.json

My package.json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server",
    "start-local": "nodemon server NODE_ENV=local",
    "start-dev": "nodemon server NODE_ENV=dev ",
    "start-stage": "nodemon server NODE_ENV=stage",
    "build": "cd Client/ && npm install && npm run build",
    "build-stage": "cd Client/ && npm install && npm run build-stage",
    "build-dev": "cd Client/ && npm install && npm run build-dev"
  },
```

and the package.json in Client looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start-dev": "ng serve --open --configuration development",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build-stage": "ng build --configuration=staging",
    "build-dev": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
```

I currently have the app deployed on heroku. I have two apps: foobar-stage & foobar. I'm using the node.js buildpack. I have different configuration values for (dev, stage & prod) set in different env files for both the client and api. The foobar app deploys fine on heroku but the foobar-stage app, despite me changing the NODE_ENV to stage runs the build command.

How do I tell heroku to run the build-stage command for foobar-stage?

Comment: Your scripts don't really make sense - build-stage tries to run itself, for example. But in general to answer the title question see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process.

Comment: I added the package.json for client. Hopefully that clears it up. I can't use heroku-postbuild, it's just the same as running build which I don't want to do for the staging app

Comment: Oh yes I see, note you can do that with --prefix too. But it's not clear why you'd think changing the env var _would_ change the script that ran - you don't have any conditional logic based on env vars as far as we can see

Comment: Is there a way to add conditional logic in the package.json file? I was hoping to do it in heroku or in the scripts